# Using language code (en) or full culture code (e.g. en-AU)?

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, internationalization

I have an application in C#/WPF which is internationalized (resource string for some languages).

Currently I am using the following codes for the resource files: default.resx, de-DE, fr-FR, es-ES, pt-BR, pt-PT, nl-NL etc.

But I have some questions:

1. E.g. for nl, there are two variants: nl-NL  (Netherlands) and nl-BE. Currently I use nl-NL, but I guess if a person from Belgium will get the default texts since nl-BE is not defined. Is this true?
2. Should I use then nl instead of nl-NL?
3. For some languages only one country is defined (e.g. hu-HU) ... what is then the difference between hu and hu-HU? I think nothing but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource search order is a bit more complex and flexible, see MSDN [Packaging and Deploying Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

For your question note item 5: if it doesn't find a specific culture like nl-NL, it searches the parent culture ([CultureInfo.Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). But the parent culture is not necessarily the culture name without the country, for example for zh-CN, it's zh-CHS. Also, there may be grandparent cultures and so on...

1. Yes
2. Yes, but be careful to select the proper parent culture name. Don't simply chop off the country
3. Yes, it doesn't matter except that the specific may load a tiny bit faster. On the other hand, you never know whether there might be another specific culture for the same language in the future. Maybe the Hungarian minority in say Romania gets its own CultureInfo...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you *typically* want to provide the resources in a neutral culture like "nl" if you can't afford to localize it both for nl-BE and nl-NL.  The resource manager will automatically fallback to the parent culture if the specific culture is not available.

Whether your customer will be happy about it is something you may find out later.  Flemish and Dutch are very similar so for that specific case it isn't likely to irk them much.  It's not so clear-cut for Brazil vs Portugal, they've had some time to develop their own patois, just like American English isn't very British anymore with diverging colours.  It just doesn't matter for hu-HU vs hu, pick hu-HU.

Background info [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756hydy4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).